# Are there any interpreted agent languages that CANNOT BE or ARE NOT compiled?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, programming-languages, agent

Regarding the three criteria of agent-oriented programming paradigm:

- support a logical system for defining the mental state of agents
- interpreted programming language for programming agents
- agentification process, for compiling agent programs into low-level executable systems (tied into second point)

**Are there interpreted programming languages that are not compiled?** To my understanding, the whole point of interpreting languages is to implement a new language with certain features, syntax, etc... but the underlying implementation eventually needs to compile down into something low-level so that it can actually be executed.

Is point 3 of the agent-oriented programming paradigm simply saying that it isn't sufficient to just theoretically define a language without implementing the language in something that can compile down into low-level code that can actually be run?

Comment: It make sense to separate between agent programming and compiler construction. Multi-agent based programming can be done in any programming language. It is a special way in using an array and methods to create a blackboard architecture. In contrast, programming languages itself and compiler development can be discussed outside of Artificial Intelligence by computer scientists. Here is the question how to convert sourcecode into machine code and to decide if this has to be in advance, just-in-time or at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [Jason](http://jason.sourceforge.net/wp/) is fully interpreted. It is a BDI agent platform. It also supports dynamic (on-the-fly) programming. You can add and organize plans in runtime and you can also save the agent mental state and load a new content with the whole system running.

Comment: excellent! i just gave a lecture yesterday about the BDI model, bratman's architecture and GOAL, so this is all very familiar jargon to me

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is a continuum between compiled and interpreted languages. And being compiled or interpreted is a property of the language *implementation* (a programming language is a *specification*, that is a document like [R5RS](https://schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/); it is *not* a software)

I strongly recommend reading Quiennec's [*Lisp In Small Pieces*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_in_Small_Pieces) book, which explains that in great detail (see also [this](https://pages.lip6.fr/Christian.Queinnec/WWW/LiSP.html)). I also recommend reading Scott's [*Programming Language Pragmatics*](https://www.cs.rochester.edu/~scott/pragmatics/) book.

BTW, Minsky's [*Society of Mind*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Society_of_Mind) book and Pitrat's [*Artificial Beings: The Conscience of a Conscious Machine*](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9780470611791) book should also interest you. And [J.Pitrat's blog](http://bootstrappingartificialintelligence.fr/WordPress3/) is also relevant.

Many "compiled" languages have "interpreted" parts. For example, in C, most `printf` implementations are "interpreting" the control format string (this is done in the `printf` function of the C standard library), even if the specification permits some form of "compilation". (and sometimes, GCC or Clang might be clever enough...)

> Are there interpreted programming languages that are not compiled?

Read also about [partial evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_evaluation) and Futamara projections

Study Common Lisp and look inside its [SBCL](https://www.sbcl.org/) implementation, which compiles into machine code every REPL interaction. Look also into [LuaJit](http://luajit.org/).

Be also aware of [JIT-compiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) libraries such as [libgccjit](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/), [GNU lightning](https://www.gnu.org/software/lightning/), [asmjit](https://github.com/asmjit/asmjit), or [LLVM](https://llvm.org/).

Comment: appreciate the references!

so in other words, the three rules for agent-oriented programming paradigm is instead:
must have logical system to represent mental state of agents && must have specification/ontology for keywords, syntax, semantics, etc && must be more than just a spec in that it has to be able to compile into something that actually runs

Comment: You gave a roundtrip through different programming languages like Lisp, Lua and C but missed out the most important one, which was invented Chuck Moore. It would make sense to explain Forth in a dominant position and explain it for agent based programming.

Comment: @ManuelRodriguez: Consider writing your own answer explaining that.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch My understanding of Forth is not great enough for an answer. If i would do so, it will read more like a question. But perhaps it would be good idea to ask how compiled stackbased languages could be used for agent based systems. Thanks for the hint.